# Xero API : Payroll AU - Leave Application and LeavePeriodStatus to create a pending approval application

Tags: xero-api

Is it possible to create a payroll AU leave application with a LeavePeriodStatus of pending approval?

I am able to make a leave request for a user but it always defaults to approved status.

I am following these docs:
https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/payrollau/leaveapplications

Which indicate you can define a LeavePeriodStatus but the two documented available types are both post approved states.

Here is where I am seeing two states but I think both are post approval.
https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/payrollau/types-and-codes/#leaveapplications

If someone knows of any undocumented state I can use to place the leave application into pending approval or to simply advise this is not possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can only create scheduled leave applications using the API.

This is the status for leave applications that are approved, but yet to be paid out to the employee.

You are not able to create draft applications.

If you want an approval process, you would need to build this on the app side of the integration so that leave is approved in your app before being sent to Xero.